# Stripe Checkout Company Name Overflows

Tags: javascript, css, stripe-payments

In Stripe Checkout, when the company name in the `data-name` attribute is too long, it overflows and the widget cannot display the whole name. Is there any way to show it completely?

Example:

```
<form action="your-server-side-code" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="publishable-key"
    data-amount="999"
    data-name="Some Long Company Name Limited"
    data-description="Widget"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
```

This code displays:

[image: Company name overflows]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: That would be a question for https://support.stripe.com/

Comment: Thanks, I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacted the support team of Stripe, and they told me that this is not possible using 'Checkout' feature as it is designed for quick integration.

They advised me to check [this doc](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js) for fully customized payment experience.